# HTML5 Video - Starting at a specific time causes jump in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, video, safari, html5-video

I'm trying to start an HTML5 video 15 seconds in. So I'm doing:

HTML

```
<video id="vid">
    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JS

```
var video = document.getElementById("vid");
video.load();
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    video.currentTime = 15;
    video.play();
}, false);
```

This seems to be working okay in Chrome. But in Safari, the video plays from the beginning for like a second, and then jumps to the 15 second mark, which is a very undesirable experience.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What video formats are you using?

Comment: I'm using mp4 and webm.